# How to fix performance issue while binding gridview without database interaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm adding some data to gridview without database interaction. While adding data to gridview it was looking fine for a few moments. After adding 20+ rows it's taking much time than expected and. Certainly, it takes seconds to fulfill an addition. It will be helpful If someone helps me to figure out the problem with the explanation.

I was using Viewstate for storing data. After searching for a solution. I have learned some drawback of ViewState and thus come back to Session to store data. But it also not helping me.

This is the aspx Page

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPayFrmAccount" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"
RowStyle-CssClass="zero" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GvPayFrmAccount_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="GvPayFrmAccountOnRowDeleting">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle"></HeaderStyle>
    <RowStyle CssClass="rowStyle"></RowStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CrAccCode" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Account Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CrAccAccount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Allocate Account" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CrAmount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Amount"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Delete">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="X" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And This is the code behind =====================

```
private void BindPayfrmAcc()
{
    DataRow dr1;
    DataColumn CrAccCode, CrAccAccount, CrAmount;
    CrAccCode = new DataColumn("CrAccCode", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    CrAccAccount = new DataColumn("CrAccAccount", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    CrAmount = new DataColumn("CrAmount", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    Current.Columns.Add(CrAccCode);
    Current.Columns.Add(CrAccAccount);
    Current.Columns.Add(CrAmount);
    int temp = 0;
    txtCrAmount.Text = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(txtCrAmount.Text), 4).ToString(".0000");
    if (btnCrSave.Text == "Add")
    {
        if (Session["Current"] != null)
        {
            Current = (DataTable)Session["Current"];
            for (int j = 0; j < Current.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (Current.Rows[j]["CrAccCode"].ToString() == txtPaidAccCode.Text)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Save",
                    "alert('This Charge Head has already been added...');", true);
                    temp++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if (temp == 0)
        {
            dr1 = Current.NewRow();
            dr1[0] = txtPaidAccCode.Text;
            dr1[1] = ddlPfrmAcc.SelectedItem.Text;
            dr1[2] = txtCrAmount.Text;
            Current.Rows.Add(dr1);
            double x = Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDouble(txtCrAmount.Text) * 10000) / 10000;
            lblCrTotalAmount.InnerText = (Convert.ToDouble(lblCrTotalAmount.InnerText) + x).ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dr1 = Current.NewRow();
        dr1[0] = txtPaidAccCode.Text;
        dr1[1] = ddlPfrmAcc.SelectedItem.Text;
        dr1[2] = txtCrAmount.Text;
        Current.Rows.Add(dr1);
        lblCrTotalAmount.InnerText = "0";
        lblCrTotalAmount.InnerText = txtCrAmount.Text;
        double x = Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDouble(txtCrAmount.Text) * 10000) / 10000;
        lblCrTotalAmount.InnerText = x.ToString();
        lblCrTotalAmount.InnerText = (Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDouble(lblCrTotalAmount.InnerText) * 10000) / 10000).ToString();
    }
}
if (Session["Current"] != null)
{
    gvPayFrmAccount.DataSource = Current;
    gvPayFrmAccount.DataBind();
    if (btnSave.Text == "Save")
    ClearData();
}
else
{
    gvPayFrmAccount.DataSource = Current;
    gvPayFrmAccount.DataBind();
    if (btnSave.Text == "Save")
    ClearData();
}
    Session["Current"] = Current;
}
```

Comment: Why no database? This is just making your code more complicated and error prone. For example, if the web app is restarted or recycled, you lose all of the data.

Comment: This part gave the user to add items and save it later. Then database came into action.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewState` and `Session` when `InProc` are infamous resource eater. You can improve performance by adding following to `web.config` (`system.web` section)

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" timeout="60"/>
```

Then make sure that **ASP.NET State Service** (`aspnet_state`) is running

and override `PageStatePersister` for the page. (This is VB.NET. I hope you can translate it to C#.)

```
Private _persister As PageStatePersister = Nothing
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property PageStatePersister As PageStatePersister
    Get
        If _persister Is Nothing Then
            _persister = New SessionPageStatePersister(Me)
        End If
        Return _persister
    End Get
End Property
```

And then keep your `DataTable` in `ViewState`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added it. But it's not helping. I find out another gridview on this page making performance issue. I think pagination can help. Though default pagination not helping at all.